# Application Error: App_Web_i3opf3mz

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

Ive got a single user who is using Win XP + Chrome (24) to login to to my site,
They enter username\password but an exception is thrown on clicking "Login"
The logs tell me "Exception App_Web_i3opf3mz Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

On Login I set a cookie but I can  tell that either the cookie is not being set or the exception is happening before it can set the cookie.

Anyone else seen this error?
I'm a bit lost on what to try...

---

FYI it appears to be if the browser supports\enabled Javascript

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: I am facing same issue. I get this issue when some one copy link and paste in another tab. Problem if i refresh tab it work fine. Don't understand why it behaving erratic on copy paste

Comment: Hey, I think it was something to do with a javascript file, also make sure you do a restart of your machine as I cant remember if I had a funny with the OS, worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

`App_Web_$SOME_CHARACTERS$` is the name of an assembly which is generated from your layouts/views/... at runtime.

Do you also log the whole stack trace or have access to the "Event Viewer" (=> eventvrw.exe)? The stack trace should help you to find the origin of the `NullReferenceException`.